# Странное поведение кучи после сборки мусора

Tags: java, tomcat, сборщик-мусора, heap, visualvm

В Tomcat развёрнуто Java EE приложение. Анализирую кучу с помощью VisualVM. Выявил закономерность: каждый раз, когда происходит сборка мусора, уменьшается размер кучи (не путать с местом, которое занимает всё её содержимое). Из этого вытекает следующее: каждая следующая сборка мусора происходит на всё более низком пороге занимаемого пространства.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На скрине часто скачущая линия — это когда я быстро перезагружаю страницу, наблюдая за происходящим.
В то же самое время если посмотреть на процесс IntelliJ Platform, такого не происходит. После каждой сборки размер кучи остаётся неизменным.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно это объяснить? Является ли это проблемой?
P.S. Лезть в кучу меня заставили подозрения на утечку памяти. Приложение стабильно падает раз в неделю-две. Очевидного виновника пока не нашёл, но увеличил максимальный размер кучи до 8 гигабайт.